# On a Centos7 system with PHP72 installed cannot get mysqli extension loaded and working

Tags: php, mysqli, typo3, centos7

mysqli.so is installed OK at /opt/remi/php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules.  Permissions are OK (the same as other extension that load properly.)

In my active php.ini conf file I added the command to load the extension (just below the [MYSQLI] :
extension=/opt/remi/php72/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so

I restart apache and can see that the extension is not loaded.  I use both the php info ( and my app that I'm trying to install TYPO3 which keeps noting the error on their install script.

centos-release-7-4.1708.el7.centos.x86_64
PHP 7.2.0 
httpd-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6.x86_64

Whats wrong?

Comment: Did you check your apache error log?

Comment: https://forum.remirepo.net/ is probably a better place to ask question related these packages

Answer (score 3):

I have similar situation, I can see the *mysqli.so* extension listed in */opt/remi/php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules* but it is not listed in the bash:

```
$ php -m
```

I used this to install mysqli extension and to restart the services:

```
$ sudo yum --enablerepo=remi-php72 install php-mysqli
$ sudo systemctl restart php-fpm nginx
```

and now I can see it listed in `php -m`.

Answer (score 2):

With RPM, you **never** have to add any extension directive. Each extension provides its configuration file.

- **php-mysqlnd** (base package) provides /etc/php.d/30-mysqli.ini and mysqli.so
- **php72-php-mysqlnd** (SCL) provides /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.d/30-mysqli.ini and mysqli.so

Adding the extension directive may raise startup issue (missing extension mysqlnd which need to be loaded first, duplicate extension, ...)

BTW, I cannot reproduce, "php -m" properly reports about mysqli extension.

Following the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instruction, should work out of the box.